# Docusign Custom Connector for Power Automate and Power Apps

Tags: docusignapi

I am developing an automated document preparation process within our Office365 environment (Word Template, SharePoint etc.) and are using Power Apps and Power Automate to prepare and send the document for authenticated signatures via Docusign. I do not want to use the 'out of the box' Docusign Power Automate connectors as I am need to invoke some of the more advanced Docusign capabilities within my Power Apps solution.

I have successfully developed my own Custom Connectors in Power Apps and Power Automate using the REST API capabilities with Docusign and successfully accomplished Oauth2 user authentication and been able to create envelopes and send documents for signature to a single recipient.

My problem is that I am wanting to send a document to **multiple recipients** using the V2.1 document REST API standards however, it seems I am bumping into an issue with the custom connector in Power Apps/Power Automate.

To ensure I had a correctly constructed JSON list, I used the built in Docusign API development environment sending the document to multiple recipients along with a document anchortag. It functioned correctly and resulted in the following JSON code:

```
    {
  "documents": [
    {
      "applyAnchorTabs": "True",
      "documentBase64": "<Base64BytesHere>",
      "documentId": "1",
      "fileExtension": "txt",
      "name": "NDA Agreement",
      "pages": "3"
    }
  ],
  "emailSubject": "Testing Docusign",
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "email": "wilson.smith@email.com",
        "name": "Wilson Smith",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "roleName": "Vice President",
        "routingOrder": "1",
        "tabs": {
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
              "documentId": "1",
              "pageNumber": "3",
              "tabLabel": "CompanySigner"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "email": "john.doe@gemail.com",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "recipientId": "2",
        "roleName": "President",
        "routingOrder": "2",
        "tabs": {
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
              "documentId": "1",
              "pageNumber": "3",
              "tabLabel": "RecipientSignature"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": "Sent"
}
```

I used this as the sample payload to import into the Request section of the DEFINITION page of the Custom Connector:

[Request section of Definition Page in Power Automate Custom Connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biGtl.png)

This results in a 'body' being developed in the REQUEST section. Opening up the BODY section of the REQUEST reveals the following elements:

[Body of Request after importing JSON payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7kiH.png)

It can be seen that there are only elements for a single recipient listed in the JSON payload.

It is further confirmed when you go to test the Custom Connector, the test page appears as follows:

[Custom Connector Test Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0gpq.png)

The test page successfully executes however, it is only sending to a single recipient. It is not identifying the need to send to multiple recipients.

I speculate that Microsoft Custom Connectors are not supporting REST V2.1 and is a limitation. I would appreciate some input on this and, if there is a workaround for this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so after crafting the question and issue above, it got me thinking about maybe importing JSON payload directly into the test page (using RAW Body display) and then tested the connector. I was surprised that the JSON code ran with MULTIPLE recipients yet, when I selected back from RAW Body mode), the test page only showed one recipient. This is very misleading.

I then thought that perhaps the connector was configured correctly and it was just a limitation in the connector test process.

I went back to Power Automate and used the multi recipient connector in my flow and was surprised to see that I now had the ability to add multiple recipients and each recipient could be set up with multiple anchor tags.

In summary, the custom connector test is a basic test environment. Going forward, I would use my full JSON payload in the RAW Body view and test it that way. Also, you need to configure the JSON payload to show multiple components to enable Power Automate to configure the use of the connector with these multiple elements.

I think this issue is worth doing a video tutorial on as I am sure many other people will bump into the same issue.

Comment: Did you make a video?